# how to autostart nanoGallery from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, nanogallery

I know this has been asked before but the answers given did not work for me and my scenario is in any case slightly different.

I am just starting to evaluate nanoGallery, which looks good for my requirement which is to run a slideshow of inline image references. But I simply want to run the slideshow from a link rather than having to display a set of thumbnails and then clicking/tapping on one to actually start the slideshow. Which doesn't seem to me to be a particularly unusual requirement, especially for a very large slideshow where the set of thumbnails would occupy far too much space on the screen.

My HTML is simply:

```
<a id="startlink" href="javascript:void(0)" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">run slide show</a>
<div id="nanoGallery">
<a id="first" href=...  data-ngdesc=... />
...
```

So I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startlink").click(function (e) {
        $("#nanoGallery").nanoGallery({
            slideshowAutoStart: true,
            ...
        });
        $("#first").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

I have tried various alternatives, including placing the script block at the end of body rather than in head, simply doing click() rather than trigger("click"), referencing $("#nanoGallery").children()[0] rather than $("#first"), and so on. I have even tried the createEvent/dispatchEvent approach as suggested elsewhere. But all I ever get is the row of (in my case empty as I have not supplied thumbnail images) thumbnail blocks which I still have to click on to start the slideshow. So it is possible that nanoGallery uses a different event or events rather than click? Has anyone actually got this to work with nanoGallery?

I have also seen a suggestion to use 'deep linking' using a hash value in the URL to identify the gallery/album in question, but I have no idea how to generate or determine this value and it may be that this only works with an online image repository such as Picasa.

Jon

Comment: As ever, I should have read the documentation more carefully. There is now an openOnStart option in v5.5.2, although it seems to be necessary to specify both the albumID and the imageID.